# Can I run a 12.04 64-bit server with only 1GB RAM?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

My friends ask me to build him a web server with 12.04 64-bit server edition in his 1GB RAM server.

Is it recommended or safe? Because I heard 64-bit system need at least 2GB RAM.

Comment: Well it is safe to use. 64 or 32 bits.

Comment: how do you define 'safe'?

Comment: safe means stable for use, especially with 1GB RAM

Answer (score 3):

The [server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html) lists the minimum requirement as 128 megabytes for all architectures. I don't see any reason why 1GB wouldn't be fine.

However, that's just the installation. How much RAM you should have to run a particular workload depends on what that workload is.

Comment: I agree with you, Robie Basak. I run a 32-bit webserver with 512MB RAM. It works efficiently, but on the other hand, I don't have that much traffic on the server as it's mainly for private use.

Comment: Well, this server is not for private use. :) And will use LEMP.

Answer (score -1):

if the CPU is x86_64 you can do that

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer to provide further explanation.